# Is there any Draw2d.js canvas destroy method?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draw2d-js

I have a question about Draw2D.js. I'm resizing the Canvas by using JQuery-ui, but when I resize the canvas I have to destroy it and create a new one ... Otherwise I'll have many canvases overlapping. If I call `canvas.destroy()` nothing works (as mentioned in the documentation).

There is any way to do a soft destroy of the canvas? Is any resize fuunctionaility in JQuery-ui?

> Thank you @MacGyver, i find solution in the second propostion. We have
>   to edit the SVG DOM :)
>
> i share my solution here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pbjh3s6/1/)!
>   it may helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to dynamically change your DOM node of your canvas, by setting the width and height manually.  Here, we have a width of 2500px and a height of 2500px.

```
<div onselectstart="javascript:/*IE8 hack*/return false" id="draw2d" style="width:2500px; height:2500px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);"></div>

canvas.setScrollArea("draw2d");
```

Or change the width and height of the DIV tag dynamically using JavaScript.

Another alternative is to set the zoom dynamically:

```
canvas.setZoom(1);  // default 1x (1:1 zoom)
canvas.setZoom(.5);  // .5x (1:2 zoom)
canvas.setZoom(2);  // 2x (2:1 zoom)
```

Then call the `app.layout()` function

Reference:

```
http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/#!/api/draw2d.Canvas
```

Comment: Today, I found another way to deal with this.  It actually answers your actual question.  canvas.clear() is a function written in draw2d touch which clears the canvas.  It's essentially a wrapper around the raphael.js functionality, but takes care of draw2d touch things, like clears events and such.

Comment: Yes i was using canvas.clear(), but what i was doing needs a soft canvas.destroy() that not exists but with the solution you give its good now.   When we use canvas.clear() its only destroys objects in the canvas, and canvas.destroy() destroy objects, canvas(Raphael paper.remove();) and events and we can't recreate it again. and thx again